# Quarkus, PanacheEntity and saving lists or sets

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson, resteasy, quarkus

I'm trying to persist an entity that contains associated entities:

```
@Entity
public class Indicator extends PanacheEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    public String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<IndicatorInput> inputs;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<IndicatorOutput> outputs;    
}
```

The collections are:

```
@Entity
public class IndicatorInput extends AbstractIndicatorValue {

    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class IndicatorOutput extends AbstractIndicatorValue {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    public String color;
    public String style;

}
```

When I try to persist an `Indicator` instance, via REST, it fails with the below error:

```
Caused by: io.quarkus.arc.ArcUndeclaredThrowableException: Error invoking subclass method
        at io.priceinsight.indicators.IndicatorResource_Subclass.create(IndicatorResource_Subclass.zig:190)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:621)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:487)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:437)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:362)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:439)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:400)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:374)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:67)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:488)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1299)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.CDIDelegatingTransactionManager.commit(CDIDelegatingTransactionManager.java:97)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.endTransaction(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:305)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:152)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:92)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:32)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:53)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.zig:168)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
        at io.priceinsight.indicators.IndicatorResource_Subclass.create(IndicatorResource_Subclass.zig:168)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1356)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:443)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3202)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2370)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:355)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:37)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:360)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1287)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3235)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3760)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1352)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "indicatorinput" violates foreign key constraint "fk6k59a1wa4ulia8tngaoimnwxa"
  Detail: Key (id)=(2) is not present in table "indicator".
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2578)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2313)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:331)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:159)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:125)
        at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:85)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
        ... 71 more
```

Or the following, depending on what I have tried

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: &#x27;void io.priceinsight.indicators.entities.AbstractIndicatorValue.$$_hibernate_write_description(java.lang.String)&#x27;
 at [Source: (io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxInputStream); line: 5, column: 22] (through reference chain: io.priceinsight.indicators.entities.Indicator[&quot;inputs&quot;]-&gt;java.util.ArrayList[0]-&gt;io.priceinsight.indicators.entities.IndicatorInput[&quot;description&quot;])
```

## What I have tried

1. change `quarkus-resteasy-jsonb` to `resteasy-jackson`
2. Change for using `List` to `Set`
3. Have tried annotating the abstract class with `@Inheritance`
4. Have tried annotating the abstract class with `@MappedSuperclass`
5. public no-arg constructor to each entity
6. Add `super();` to the constructor body
7. Add `@RegisterForReflection` to entities
8. Add `implements Serializable` to entities
9. Used `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a combination of a few issues here.

1. `PanacheEntity` itself contains `id` field. So you need to either remove your `id` field from `Indicator` **or** make `Indicator` extend `PanacheEntityBase`.
2. Your `id` is private which only brings issues on deserialization(especially with `PanacheEntity` which already have `id` field). So make it either public or create getters and setters.
3. I also added strategy to `@GeneratedValue` as Identity to make it incrementable

Below is a working implementation for me. There's no example of `AbstractIndicatorValue`, so I'm assuming it's class that extends `PanacheEntity`.

- IndicatorInput.java

```java
@Entity
// Make AbstractIndicatorValue extend PanacheEntityBase
public class IndicatorInput extends PanacheEntityBase {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
}
```

- IndicatorOutput.java

```java
@Entity
// Make AbstractIndicatorValue extend PanacheEntityBase
public class IndicatorOutput extends PanacheEntityBase {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
    public String color;
    public String style;
}
```

- Indicator.java

```java
@Entity
public class Indicator extends PanacheEntityBase {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<IndicatorInput> inputs;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<IndicatorOutput> outputs;
}
```